# how to organize and view data in fabrik

Tags: database

Hello my db is a simple questionnaire with questions, choice,choices's results
like
Name-----QUESTION-----YES/NO-----RESULT
Paul-------thequestion --------YES-----------A

At the end i'll need to gather data according to answer to question, result and name..and mainly need to know how many respond to this queri

The original idea was to see data in a excel table list style and query straight the column of interest.
But there are around 30 questions, and the text is long..so the table will come out very large and not nice to work with
How can i solve this?
I was think to create a form with all the question /answer/result , where i can choose those i want to queries, and have displayed all the records that respond to this (or even only the number of records)
Is it a good way or may be better alternatives?
How would i do a similar form, a part of creating all the question/button ecc?
thanks

at themoment waiting for howo to go on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok i have narrowed down theneed:

Answer (score 1):

ok narrowed down theneed:
see the page
https://artcounseloraroma.net/index.php/component/fabrik/list/1

i have set for now only 5 questions(D1,D2...) and the list is growing in vertical..i want to expand in horizontal instead
I don't know where to use the no-wrap instruction

Then, may be event more important..you see in top i have used 2 elements for queryng
At the end they will be a lot of elemnts, i want to position them horizontally,3,4 elemnts per row
And i need to put the text question (the ones inD1,D2..) that are diplay elements together with the filtering elemnts
So for the filtering area i want
question, filter element1, filter element2, filter element3,
and again the same for next row..

Answer (score 0):

i have found this
http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/create-a-search-form/

which is not too bad but i don't like too much
What i would like to have is that as soon as i change a search parameter, in the same page, underneath, i will see all the filtered data

or maybe there are better alternatives?